# Use $=$ or $\in$ for intervals?

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory

Say I for example have 
$
\int_0^1 x\, dx
$, 
is it correct to write the interval of $x$ as $x\in[0,1]$ or $x=[0,1]$?

Or for example the curve $\mathbf r(t)=3\cos t\hat{i} + 2 \sin t \hat{j}$, is it correct to write $t\in[0,2\pi]$ or $t=[0,2\pi]$?

Comment: I️ really don’t think you should use the equal sign

Comment: We always use $\in$ whenever we want to denote that an "element belongs to a set". Here, $x$ or $t$ is our element and the interval is our set.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on the usage. If $a=0$ and $b=1$ then $[a, b] = [0, 1]$.

If on the otherhand you wish to say some value $x$ can range in values between $a$ and $b$, then you say $x \in [a, b]$.

$x = [a, b]$ means that $x$ is not a number, but rather an interval.

So in your case:

$\int_{0}^{1}xdx$ means that $x$ ranges from $0$ to $1$, hence $x \in [0, 1]$ OR $x \in (0, 1)$ (more on this below).

In the second example of your curve $r(t)$, definitely $t \in [0, 2\pi]$.

The integral example is a tad misleading because if you remove on point from an integral, it does not change the integral, so it's difficult to say whether the interval includes the limits or not, as the integral is written the same regardless. But in any scenario, it is still "$\in$".

Comment: Hi! In ''*... $x$ can range in values between $a$ and $b$, then you say $x\in [a,b]$.*'', is $x$ here an **element**? And in ''*$x=[a,b]$ means that $x$ is not a number, but rather an interval.*'', is $x$ here a **set**?

Comment: @Donsert Sorry for the late reply. Yes and yes.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen the notation $x = [0,1]$ before while the notations $x \in [0,1]$ and $0 \leq x \leq 1$ are commonly used. Note that if $x = [0,1]$ then $x$ is not an element of $[0,1]$ so the statements are not equivalent in the first place which would introduce an ambiguity into the notation.

Comment: That's a bit odd. You've never seen anything like "Let $\Omega = [0, 1]$, let's calculate $\int_{\Omega} f(x)dx$"?

Comment: @OriaGruber Yes I have but note that your $\Omega$ is distinct from the $x$ in the integral you've given. It's important to distinguish between a set and the elements of the set which are muddled if you allow the notation $x=[0,1]$ to mean $x \in [0,1]$.